# Using \inputminted from lyx with relative path

Tags: lyx, minted, lyx-layouts

I'm using the [minted](http://code.google.com/p/minted/) package with lyx. I want to use `\inputminted` and *must* be able to specify a relative path (to share between machines with different home directory names).

The problem is that the working directory when `\inputminted` is invoked is `/tmp/lyxbuf_tmp`. [This mailing list post from 2009](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.lyx.general/60099) discusses this exact problem of copying external material to this directory, but there appears to be no resolution that I can find.

Can anyone explain how to make a `minted.layout` file which would allow me to use `\inputminted` and have the desired effect of including an external source code file?

Alternatively can anyone suggest any ways to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways:

## Create an external variable template.

This is the best way but will take some time to understand and set up. 
Go to Tools > Customization > Section 6 (Including External Material)

There are many path variables. For example:

```
$$AbsOrRelPathParent The file path, absolute or relative to the LyX document.
$$FPath The path part of $$FName (absolute name or relative to the LyX document).
$$RelPathMaster The file path, relative to the master LyX document.
$$RelPathParent The file path, relative to the LyX document.
```

## Use a script (e.g. Python or Bash) to do the substitution.

This is a little hackish but gives you complete control. Make a converter (again, see the Customization manual for details) by going to Tools > Preferences > File Handling > Converters. Edit the `converter` field. See the following screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on @scottkosty's answer! I put this in my ~/.lyx/external_templates folder, and then went to Insert > File > External Material and then select minted. It's not as well parametrized as it could be, but I don't have any more time to fiddle with this.

```
Template MintedSource
    GuiName "Minted Source Code"
    HelpText
        Run \inputminted{}
    HelpTextEnd
    InputFormat text
    FileFilter "*"
    AutomaticProduction true
    Preview InstantPreview
    Format PDFLaTeX
        Product "\\inputminted[linenos,fontsize=\\footnotesize,baselinestretch=1]{python}{$$AbsPath$$Basename$$Extension}"

        Requirement "underscore"
        Requirement "minted"

        UpdateFormat text
        UpdateResult "$$AbsPath$$Basename$$Extension"
        ReferencedFile text "$$AbsPath$$Basename$$Extension"
    FormatEnd
TemplateEnd
```

Comment: How do we specify linenos?

Comment: Note that LyX will ship a minted external template with version 2.3.0. You are welcome to test the beta when it is out soon.