# Getting minted and LyX work together

Tags: lyx, minted, report, lyx-layouts

I need to insert code in my report, so I decided to use minted with LyX, my usual editor. I found a solution for getting minted and LyX together in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114243/using-inputminted-from-lyx-with-relative-path) (pwaller answer), by adding a custom template for minted in the external_templates directory. Here is the template:

```
Template MintedSource
    GuiName "Minted Source Code"
    HelpText
        Run \inputminted{}
    HelpTextEnd
    InputFormat text
    FileFilter "*"
    AutomaticProduction true
    Preview InstantPreview
    Format PDFLaTeX
        Product "\\inputminted[linenos,fontsize=\\footnotesize,baselinestretch=1]{python}{$$AbsPath$$Basename$$Extension}"

        Requirement "underscore"
        Requirement "minted"

        UpdateFormat text
        UpdateResult "$$AbsPath$$Basename$$Extension"
        ReferencedFile text "$$AbsPath$$Basename$$Extension"
    FormatEnd
TemplateEnd
```

According to the [LyX Documentation](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/UserDir), external templates should be placed in C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\LyX\external_templates directory. So I copied the minted template there, under multiple extensions (.lyx, .layout and none).

Either way, the new template won't show up in Insert > File > External Material gui. Is there anything wrong I did? Is there a easiest way to deal with minted in LyX? (the `\inputminted` command won't work, reasons explained in [the same post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114243/using-inputminted-from-lyx-with-relative-path).

Comment: external_templates is a file. It does not have an extension. That might be weird from a Windows perspective but for Unix it is normal. So it is just a text file but with no extension (note that the wiki link you linked to lists "external_templates" as a "file"). When doing this, be aware of this bug: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/3983 . That is, if you use other external templates, copy them from the system external_templates file.

Comment: well thanks, didn't know why I thought `external_templates` was a folder…

Comment: It is understandable. "templates", "examples", "doc" are all folders in the LyX user directory, so in some sense it is strange that "external_templates" is not.

Comment: @scottkosty Could you write up an answer?

Answer (score 1):

external_templates is a file. So you should remove (backup) the external_templates folder you created, and create a text file and paste your external template in it. When doing this, be aware of this bug: lyx.org/trac/ticket/3983. That is, if you use other external templates, copy them from the system external_templates file.

The external_templates file does not have an extension. That might be weird from a Windows perspective but for Unix it is normal. So it is just a text file but with no extension.